# Merging multiple concurrent gps tracks

Tags: gps, tracklog, movement-data

I have GPS tracks from 2 or more devices in multiple vehicles. At least one device reports the vehicle's position to a webui approximately every 5 seconds assuming that it has a cellular data connection. the second device logs its position to a file every second while it is functioning, however, it is not always functioning for the entire duration of the journey.

I would like to take these two tracks and merge them into a single track for analysis purposes. My naive first approach was to use the timestamps in the file and the webui to synchronize the tracks, however, there is no shared clock between the data stored from the two devices and I am not convinced that there is a constant delay in the webui log.

How can I merge the tracks, synchronize the timestamps, and interleave the points appropriately?

Comment: What GIS system are you using, license levels and versions?

Comment: not really using a GIS system, writing code in Python, however, it's more a process question, if you have a process that works in a particular GIS system, I can likely figure out how to do something similar in Python

Comment: @BjornHarpe Did you ever figure this out? I'm in a [similar situation myself](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/462221/162234).

Comment: We ended up solving it by giving precedence to the datasource with better temporal resolution and discarded any "colliding" records