# How can I consolidate / deduplicate processed AIS data from different stations?

Tags: latitude-longitude, tracking, duplication

#### Context

I have received processed [AIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_identification_system) data from different AIS receiver stations from which I need to construct trajectories for each vessel. The data has the following columns:

- timestamp
- vessel ID
- lat
- lon
- direction of vessel
- speed of vessel
- AIS station ID

The area that the AIS receiver stations cover overlap each other, so a single vessel location is often picked up by different stations.
In my case the AIS message were not timestamped when sent by the vessel, they were timestamped by each receiving station (I believe that's how AIS works in general). As the stations are not synced to each other, the timestamp differs unfortunately. So station A indicates that the vessel is at location X at time T1, but station B indicates the same vessel is at the same location at time T2.

Below plot shows two trajectories of the same vessel, but timestamped by two different stations:

[image]

This is part of the sample data used for the plot:

|  | timestamp | lat | lon | direction | speed | station |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2022-08-01 14:00:44.8 | 52.3609 | 4.88598 | 313 | 4.3 | a |
| 6 | 2022-08-01 14:00:54.6 | 52.361 | 4.88584 | 318.3 | 0.8 | a |
| 7 | 2022-08-01 14:01:05.2 | 52.361 | 4.88579 | 317.5 | 0.2 | a |
| 8 | 2022-08-01 14:02:03.8 | 52.3611 | 4.88568 | 309.5 | 0.2 | a |
| 9 | 2022-08-01 14:02:11.1 | 52.3594 | 4.88842 | 326.7 | 4.3 | b |
| 10 | 2022-08-01 14:02:12.2 | 52.3595 | 4.88828 | 328.8 | 4.3 | b |
| 11 | 2022-08-01 14:02:13.2 | 52.3597 | 4.88814 | 328.8 | 4.3 | b |

Note that this example is simplified w.r.t. to the real data on the following aspects:

- In reality I can have up to 5 stations picking up the location, this exampe only has 2.
- In reality different stations capture different segments of the track. The example has a nearly perfect overlap, but oftentimes e.g. the first 4 points are registered by station A, the 3rd until the 7th points is from station B (and station A has no info there), etc...

#### Question

How can I deduplicate this into a single trajectory per vessel, where each point has 1 location and 1 timestamp? I don't care for the exact time a vessel was there (i.e. what time station A or B tells me), but I do care about consistency and that each point consecutively follows the previous point timewise.

#### What I've tried

- If I simply sort the points by the timestamp, ignore the stations and connect all points by a line, I get a trajectory that jumps back and forth.
- If I just pick one station and ignore all the others, my data shows gaps in certain geographic areas that are not covered by the chosen station.
- For the example I tried shifting the time of station b by 3 minutes and 14 seconds (the average difference), but the time difference between stations is not constant, so I don't know how to expand this for all the data.

Comment: Several questions...

How much skew are you willing to accept between stations? 

Do I Understand that the data is being transmitted by a device, multiple stations then receive that transmission and its the local timestamp on the receiving station that varies from station to station?

Is it safe to assume that either the stations are all in a single timezone or the timestamps have been normalised to a single timezone?

Do you have sample data you can share in addition to the graphical representation?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying questions. Skew: not sure what that means in this context? Yes, your understanding of the transmitter/station/timestamp relation is correct. All stations are in a single timezone, in my case the stations reside within a rough bounding box of 20 x 20 km. I will share sample data later today.

Comment: @BjornHarpe I've added a sample